# Javascript condense if statement

Tags: javascript

I have an if statement in javascript that is

```
if(prop < 0 || trans < 0 || queue < 0 || proc < 0 
    || prop > 1 || trans > 1 || queue > 1 || proc > 1 
    || prop == "" || trans == "" || queue == "" || proc == ""){
```

Is there a way to condense this? For `prop`, `trans`, `queue`, and `proc`. I want to create an if statement if the values do not fall to be between 0 and 1 or if it has an empty string value

Comment: Are those variables guaranteed to be strings?

Comment: Well i get their values by `document.getElementById('prop').value` and the user should know to input integers

Comment: @Bijan: Then it's a string. You should probably parse it first.

Comment: are you checking if ANY are out of range? or all-at-the-same-time? if it's any, then this is basically what you have to do. for the all-at-the-same-time, you can do stuff like `if (prop + trans + queue + proc == '')`

Comment: It is if any are out of range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building off of [Jordan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27237889/404623):

```
var checkThese = [prop, trans, queue, proc];
var result = checkTruthinessOf(checkThese);

function checkTruthinessOf(things) {
    return things.every(function(el) {
       return (el < 0 || el > 1 || el === "");
    });
}
```

See [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 4):

```
var checkThese = [prop, trans, queue, proc];
var result = checkTruthinessOf(checkThese);

function checkTruthinessOf(things) {
    var returnValue = false;
    [].forEach.call(things, function(thing){
       if (thing < 0 || thing > 1 || thing == "") returnValue = true;
    });
    return returnValue;
};
```

Comment: Why not `checkThese.forEach(function(thing){`?  Why do you need `.call` there?

Comment: Just the syntax I use most often. I think Doug Crockford actually suggests it

Comment: Also, `return true;` inside the `forEach`'s callback won't do anything!  That won't return from your `checkTruthinessOf` function.

Comment: [citation needed] :-P  I doubt creating a new array just to get it's `forEach` method when you are using it on an array is *not* the best practice.

Comment: You will need a strict operator for `=== ""`, otherwise `0` will be a false positive.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I was wrong. I was referencing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSGEjv3Tqo0, but he actually suggests the opposite :p

Comment: @RocketHazmat no problem. He gives some of the best talks!

Answer (score 1):

I picked up this practice from jQuery. It eliminates the extra array and just passes in as many arguments as you like. Then use rink's function to validate all it at once.

```
var result = checkTruthinessOf(prop, trans, queue, proc);

function checkTruthinessOf(/*unlimited arguments*/) {
   return Array.prototype.every.call(arguments, function(thing) {
       return (thing < 0 || thing > 1 || thing === "");
    });
}
```